# When you have choices, are you always right?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

3 times in the story I got a choice to make between who is good and who is a cult member. (Like once it was between 2 twins that one of them was a cult member and the other was a priestess, or another one was between the two Kings of sparta)

Every time, I took a wild guess because for me, it looked that they both had proof that they were innocent and proof that they might be in the cult. Lucky me, I always got it right.

But now I'm wondering: In those choices, are you just always right? Whatever you pick the story will adapt to say you were right or was I just lucky?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're not always right. For example, I got the twin sisters wrong. As far as I remember, choosing the right twin is a little tricky, the evidence doesn't clearly indicate which one is the cultist. But for the two kings of Sparta you gather clues from other cultists that help you decide which king is the cultist (in fact, once you have all the clues the sage can be unveiled in the cultist menu). I think depending on your earlier choices you may not get all the necessary clues and then you have to guess, and you may get it wrong as well.

Comment: You can tell the twins apart if you (rot13) purpx gurz va nqinapr jvgu Vxnebf, or you can tell because the cultist xrrcf gnyxvat nobhg gur Sngrf.

Comment: For anyone confused by the comment above, it is a message using [a simple cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) to hide spoilers.

Comment: So I guess I'm just a lucky Son of a B.